# Losing color when rasterizing some vectors

Tags: pdf, png, ghostscript, rasterizing

I have a process that rasterize PDFs with lots os vector objects in form of clothes pieces into high definition PNGs using Ghostscript in python. In some cases I'm seeing that some of these pieces are losing the color in the output. My believe its that its related to the fact that there are lots (maybe thousands?) of vectors in each piece.

[image]

You can notice that the image on the left (opened in illustrator) has a piece that's not showing in the rasterized image (right). I may be wrong and it's not the quantity of vectors that are affecting but I don't have another lead at the moment since there is not error message or anything. Why could this be happening?

Ghostcript version: Ghostscript 9.53.3

Command I'm using to run it:

```
gs -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -o output_file_path -dBufferSpace=2000000000 -dNumRenderingThreads=4 -dMaxBitmap=2147483647 -f input_file_path
```

Comment: You haven't said which version of Ghostscript you are using, what command line, or what the back channel says, all of which are important information. The most likely explanation is a bug, but without all that information and an example file there's absolutely no way to tell. I'm afraid pictures of the problem really don't help with diagnosis.  If you think you've found a bug you should report it. You will need all he same information to report a bug.

Comment: True. sorry, I edited the post and added the version and command I'm using

Comment: Well you could try dropping the NumRenderingThreads, or lowering the resolution, but it seems to me like that should work, so you've probably found a bug. There is a newer release (9.54.0) you could try in the hope its been fixed, and there will be another release along this month. Beyond that, you probably need to report a bug.

Comment: I tried both of those but still having the same issue. I filed a bug so maybe somebody can help me with that there. Will add the link to the bug report [here](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=704388) just for the record. Thanks @KenS